# How to perform a quick search against Ms access database table in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, search

hi guys i have a table from Ms access called VMS and i want to make a simple search against different fields of the table and display it in datagridview of C# 2010, here is the code i try for the field "plate no" but not works has an error

```
private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vMSDataGridView.DataSource = 
        this.vMSDataSet.VMS.Select("PlateNo ="  & textBox10.Text);
 }
```

any help will be appritiated!

Comment: Can you consider to share the error message with us?

Answer (score 1):

if PlateNo is a string column, as it seems from your code, then you should write

```
this.vMSDataSet.VMS.Select("PlateNo ='"  + textBox10.Text + "'");
```

Comment: wow! steve u r a saviour! it works right,  am a beginner for C# u hav no idea how many days i suffer for dis so now i can make a search for every fields by using radio buttons with if statement. thank you very much steve